# UIImagePickerController camera: how to use full screen? (black subview at the bottom)

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I try to use `UIImagePickerController` to record a video with the camera. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit; import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    
    private var imagePickerControllerView = UIImagePickerController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePickerControllerView.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        imagePickerControllerView.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        containerView.addSubview(imagePickerControllerView.view)
        imagePickerControllerView.sourceType = .camera
        imagePickerControllerView.allowsEditing = false
        imagePickerControllerView.cameraCaptureMode = .video
        imagePickerControllerView.cameraDevice = .front
        imagePickerControllerView.showsCameraControls = false
        imagePickerControllerView.videoQuality = .typeIFrame1280x720
    }
}
```

I end up with a black subview at the bottom of the screen, though I want to implement my own controls and make the image picker view go full screen.

[image]

What to do here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Because you said `imagePickerControllerView.showsCameraControls = false`? You removed the controls so that area is empty.

Comment: @matt Thank you for the answer. So I understand that this black space is the original space for the controls, but what I actually want to do is to implement custom controls and completely remove this black bar. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use AVFoundation camera instead of picker?

Comment: I have also faced this issue. Digging deeper using the Debug View Hierarchy revealed that there is an internal view controller named `CAMPreviewViewController` that is responsible for showing the camera preview. This view controller appears to have a fixed width and height frame and is not laid out properly. This could be a bug in UIImagePickerController and you should probably report it to Apple using Feedback Assistant. I will try to find a workaround if none was found already and add it as an answer.